# After mocking through autofac, actual implementation of service is getting called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofac, mstest

Am writing unit test cases for the project,
Service class is mocked and even after mocking actual implementation is getting called,Please suggest the way to mock properly. So that service method gets mocked properly.G

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void CustomerTest()
    {
      using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
      {
        //For testing,Created dummy object of customer having datatable dt
        var response = Task.FromResult(customer(dt))
        // Arrange - configure the mock
        mock.Mock<ICustomerService>().Setup(x => x.GetCustomerDetails(It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(response);
        var sut = mock.Create<CustomerViewModel>();

        // Act
        var actual = sut.GetCustomerInfo("12345", "Name");

        // Assert - assert on the mock
        mock.Mock<ICustomerService>().Verify(x => x.GetCustomerDetails(It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<string>(),Times.Once());
        Assert.AreEqual(response, actual);
      }
    }
```

I have to mock the service, so that actual method of service doesnt get invoked.

Comment: You are unit testing a view model? What logic does it have in it? You need to post a [MCVE].

Comment: Yes, Its unit test case of view Model. In getCustomerInfo we are calling the method(getCustomerDetails) of service which returns async task.

Comment: To be clear, Autofac isn't mocking anything - Moq handles the work and dynamically creates mocks as needed, jamming them into an Autofac container. However, it doesn't appear you're actually using any of that functionality, so I might recommend removing it from the equation and JUST using Moq.

Comment: Yes Moq actually worked, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make the service method virtual, this is what worked for me with NUnit.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the mocked member is async from the fact that you are using `Task.FromResult` for the response

May the Test async as well and await the subject under test

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task CustomerTest() {
    using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose()) {
        //For testing,Created dummy object of customer having datatable dt
        var response = customer(dt);
        // Arrange - configure the mock
        mock.Mock<ICustomerService>()
            .Setup(_ => _.GetCustomerDetails(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(response);

        var sut = mock.Create<CustomerViewModel>();

        // Act
        var actual = await sut.GetCustomerInfo("12345", "Name");

        // Assert - assert on the mock
        mock.Mock<ICustomerService>()
            .Verify(_ => _.GetCustomerDetails(It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<string>(), Times.Once());
        Assert.AreEqual(response, actual);
    }
}
```

The above assumes the mocked interface is explicitly injected into the subject under test

```
public class CustomerViewModel {

    public CustomerViewModel(ICustomerService service) {
        //...
    }

    //...

    public Task<Customer> GetCustomerInfo(string id, string name) {
        //...calls ICustomerService.GetCustomerDetails(id, name);
    }
}
```